# Rank and unrank permutations with just one cycle

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, permutation, ranking

I want to rank and unrank permutations with one cycle in lexicographical order with a given len.

A permutation with one cycles is where you can visit in this cycle each element.

`p:= (2,3,1)` is a permutation with one cycle. Has rank 1.

`p:= (3,1,2)` has 1 cycle too, but rank 2, because the permutation is lexicographical greater the frist so it becomes a greater rank.

`p:= (1,2,3)` is a permutation with 3 cycles. `(1),(2),(3)`

How can I efficently rank (permutation with one cycle to rank) and unrank (rank + len to permutation with one cycle) in lexicographical order? I have no idea how to archive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution for ranking. We know that a permutations of length `n` has `n-1`! permutations with one cycle. Due to this knowledge we can come to the following solution.

Ranking: example `2341`

We start to calculating the rank with the 1 position this gives `(n-1[position])! as tempvalue`. Then we calculating the index of the `2` which is 0, because `1` is falling out through it creates the cycle (1). To complete the calculating for the first position we need to multiply the `index` of the element with the `tempvalue`, which leads to 0 as `temprank_0`. 
Now we continue this steps for the remaining positions to add `temprank_0+temprank_1+temprank_2+temprank_4 = 0`

Unranking: `4` for permutation len 4:

We divide the rank through `(n-2[postion+1])!` which leads `2` which is the index of `1234` which dont create a cycle  so the 1 position of the permutation is `4` . Then we subtract `2 times (n-2)!`from `4`. 
This we continue this twice. So we have `412`. So in the end we add just the remaining value `3` end we get the permutation `4123` .