# Using itertools.permutations with constraints to solve Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

I am currently working on a Python code to solve Traveling Salesman Problem.
Basically, you need to find the shortest distance possible when visiting several points on a map and returning back to the origin.

The part of my code that is calculating the distance is working just fine, but at the moment it is taking way too long to iterate through all possible permutations and calculate the respective distances.

Currently I am using `itertools.permutations`  to generate all possible paths to visit these points.

However, because I return to the origin, I do not need to calculate the solutions where the origin changes as these will return the same distances. So basically, I just wanna permute all entries that come after the first entry in my list.

Additionally, `[0, 1, 2, 3]` gives the same distance as `[0, 3, 2, 1]` so I want to get rid of these reverse duplicates as well.

Here is the part of the code that is responsible for the permutations:

```
import itertools
import random

max_x = 510
max_y = 510

number_points = int(input("Enter number of points: "))
print("")
coords_list = []

i = 0

while i < number_points:
    a = [random.randint(10, max_x), random.randint(10, max_y)]
    coords_list.append(a)
    print("Point", i, "has coords", a)

    i = i + 1

print("")


# All possible permutations


b = list(itertools.permutations(coords_list, number_points))
print(b)
print("")
print(len(b))
```

Comment: TSP is intractable for large N. You need to use a better algorithm than brute force which has time complexity n!. So for even size 15, you have over a trillion things to search.

Comment: Beware for n Points you just need (n-1)! Permutations not n!/2 because you need permutations with just one cycle. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800684/rank-and-unrank-permutations-with-just-one-cycle

Answer (score 0):

Docuemntation of itertools permutation is as such:

```
Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value.
```

Change way of arranging points, list of point inside tuple.
For removing duplicate iterate through list and write custom rule, no builtin available in python 3.8